# Low R2 but high MAPE

Tags: machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn, neural-network

I'm currently working on a project where I have to solve a regression based problem. I basically have to try different models and compare the accuracy of each one. Until now I've tried Decision Trees, Random Forests and Bagging.Currently,I'm trying out ANN's.The metrics that I'm using to evaluate the model performance are the R2 score, RMSE and MAPE. For the first 3 models, the results that I'm getting are:
Decision Tree:
R2: 0.608
RMSE:11.640681667132872
MAPE:78.73%

Bagging:
R2: 0.752
RMSE:9.193
MAPE:78.46%


Random Forest:
R2: 0.726
RMSE:9.731
MAPE: 78.27%

However, with the ANN, the results that I'm getting are really baffling.
R2:0.264
RMSE:12.034
MAPE:88.73%

As you can see, although the R2 score is very low compared to the other models, the MAPE accuracy is surprisingly high. Can anyone please give me some insight as to why this might be happening?

The code that I'm using for calculating the MAPE accuracy is:

```
#Function to calculate MAPE accuracy
def evaluate(model, test_features, test_labels):
    predictions = model.predict(test_features)
    errors = abs(predictions - test_labels)
    mape = 100 * np.mean(errors / test_labels)
    accuracy = 100 - mape
    print('Model Performance')
    print('Average Error: {:0.4f} degrees.'.format(np.mean(errors)))
    print('Accuracy = {:0.2f}%.'.format(accuracy))

    return accuracy
```

P.S. I'm using the hold out method of evaluation.

Comment: Take a look https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/327464/mape-vs-r-squared-in-regression-models https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11636/the-difference-between-mse-and-mape